# Rails Javascript haml variable creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have Code pasted below for creation of variables in javascript with rails + javascript variables

```
:javascript
$( ".form-control" ).each(function( index ) {


var mix = $( this ).attr("id").split("_");
var e_array = mix.shift();
var e_name = mix.join("_");

var error = "#{@account.errors[:" + e_name +"]}";

//var error = error[":" + ];
alert(error);



console.log( "#{@account.errors}");
});
```

Why does the array return empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `"#{@account.errors['"+e_name+"']}";`